# I want hover animation only on card hover not on body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want run this animation only on card `hover` and not on `body`.

Here is [codepen link](http://codepen.io/ariona/pen/JopOOr?mc_cid=494a4583f0&mc_eid=b20b368441)

I've tried with

```js
var card = $(".card");
card.on("mousemove", function(e) {
  var ax = -($(window).innerWidth() / 2 - e.pageX) / 20;
  var ay = ($(window).innerHeight() / 2 - e.pageY) / 10;
  card.attr("style", "transform: rotateY(" + ax + "deg) rotateX(" + ay + "deg);-webkit-transform: rotateY(" + ax + "deg) rotateX(" + ay + "deg);-moz-transform: rotateY(" + ax + "deg) rotateX(" + ay + "deg)");
});
```

but it looks weird

Comment: I've tried with `var card = $(".card");

card.on("mousemove",function(e) {  
  var ax = -($(window).innerWidth()/2- e.pageX)/20;
  var ay = ($(window).innerHeight()/2- e.pageY)/10;
  card.attr("style", "transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-webkit-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-moz-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg)");
});` but it looks weird

Comment: see this body not move http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPBXOX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emPzyK)?

Changes:

```
//pointer-events: none;
```

and

```
$(".card").on("mousemove",function(e) {
```

Comment: this is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change JS to following content:

```
 var card = $(".card-content");

 $(document).on("mousemove",function(e) {  
  var ax = -($(window).innerWidth()/2- e.pageX)/20;
  var ay = ($(window).innerHeight()/2- e.pageY)/10;
  card.attr("style", "transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-  webkit-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-moz-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg)");
```

});

I tried it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbyOpM)

The jquery is on `$(document).on("mousemove"...` etc.

This needs to change to `$(".card").on("mousemove"`

And the css property: `pointer-events:none;` needs to be removed.

And it works :) Cheers...

> Taking/using others code without permission is theft

Answer (score 0):

change in your script

```
var card = $(".card-content");
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJxjKL)